# Terminate an application with ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, system-tray, contextmenustrip

I want to hide my application in system tray when I click the `Form Closing` button(clasic red X button). I provided with this code;

```
    private void Ana_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
    {            
        e.Cancel = true; 
        this.Hide();          
    }
```

So, the application is stil running in the `system tray`. I have added a `ContextMenuStrip` and when I right click on mouse `ContextMenuStrip` a `Close` button comes up but when I click that `Close` button the application is still running.
 I want to terminate the application when I click that `Close` button. Here is my code:

```
   private void kapatToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Close
   {
        DialogResult ext;
        ext = MessageBox.Show("Çıkmak İstediğinizden Emin misiniz?", "Onay", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (ext == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();                
        }       
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();                      
    }
```

Comment: It's because application itself prevent from closing (Your first snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Application.Exit()` will actually attempt to close all your forms, and because your `FormClosing` is hard coded to be cancelled, then it cannot complete the task.

One option with your current structure would be to create an `AllowClose` flag. This could be a property of the Form, or it could be a global static value.

For example:

```
//in your form
public bool AllowClose {get;set;}

private void Ana_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    if(!AllowClose)
    {            
        e.Cancel = true; 
        this.Hide();  
    }        
}

//in your context menu event
private void kapatToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Close
{

    DialogResult ext;
    ext = MessageBox.Show("Çıkmak İstediğinizden Emin misiniz?", "Onay", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (ext == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.AllowClose = true;
        Application.Exit();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
bool isClosing = false;


 private void Ana_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
    {            
        if(!isClosing)
        {
           e.Cancel = true; 
           this.Hide();          
        }
    }




private void kapatToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Close
    {
        DialogResult ext;
        isClosing = true;

        ext = MessageBox.Show("Çıkmak İstediğinizden Emin misiniz?", "Onay", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (ext == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();

        }       
    }
```

Comment: This causes the same problem, and stops the original feature from working. You want `if(!isClosing)`